# Where Can I Find the CSS file to Edit My Current Wordpress Theme

Tags: wordpress, wordpress-theming

I am trying to change the background color of my Wordpress site, as well as the size of images I use on this site. However, I can't find the CSS file that specifies these properties for my Wordpress site.

If I can edit it, where is the CSS file that specifies these properties for my Wordpress site located?

Comment: Thank you so much for editing ..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Which theme do you use?

The most of wordpress themes have a style.css in their parent folder that finds in: wp-content/themes/your-theme.

If you can't find this file, you can add styles in custom CSS on the "Theme Options" in /wp-admin.

PD: I recommend you to use a child theme because if you need in the future to update the theme, all your modifications in it will lose.

Comment: Thanks.I found it as you said inside content folder.

Comment: It works? If it works, can you mark this like the correct answer?

Answer (score 3):

You can edit CSS from admin panel also

- Go to **Dashboard > Appearance > Editor** and click on style.css.

here you can edit the files directly from this window and hit save when you’re done. 
[image]

or

You can edit CSS file located at ,

- Go to **wp-content > themes > YOUR THEME NAME**  and try to finder a folder that houses the css files. They are usually named CSS stylesheets or styles.